# Temporary invert primary <=> secondary on AWS Route53 DNS Failover setup

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, failover, amazon-route53

I have a Route53 DNS Failover setup associated with Health Checks running fine but periodically we need to invert primary <=> secondary just for an hour or two for maintenance.

How is the best practice for this? Any simple way to achieve that?

Any input is appreciated!! 
Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's best practice but you can do the following.

mysite.example.com failover (primary) (evaluate target health + cacluated health check attached) --> site1.example.com (associated with regular hc)

mysite.example.com  failover (secondary) (evaluate target health + cacluated health check attached) --> site2.example.com (associated with regular hc)

You can create two calculated health checks with no children.  Associate the health checks with each site.  If the child health check (site1) becomes unhealthy, Route 53 to failover to site2.  If you invert the status of your calculated health check, Route 53 will then failover to site 2.  When you are down, uninvert the health check.